# MySQL selection based on AVG function

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select all Countries which won more than the average number of (any) medal across all countries from the table below:

[image: Results Table]

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| idRESULTS | STATUS      | MEDALS | EVENTS_idEVENTS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY | EVENTS_VARIOUS_SPORTS_SPORTS_ID | awarded_medals_medal-id |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| results1  | DID-NOT-WIN | SILVER | TEN             | MS                         | RUS-WTA                       | RUS                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       2 |
| results1  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN             | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       3 |
| results2  | DID-NOT-WIN | BRONZE | ATH             | JG                         | USA-TF-MEN                    | USA                                     | TRACK-AND-FIELD                 |                       3 |
| results2  | WON         | GOLD   | ATH             | UB                         | JAM-TF-MEN                    | JAM                                     | TRACK-AND-FIELD                 |                       1 |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | SW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       3 |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     | WOMENS_TENNIS                   |                       1 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I am using this code :

```
CREATE VIEW `Countries_Athletes_who_wo_Gold` AS
select * from results where medals = 'Gold'

select EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY, medals from countries_athletes_who_wo_gold
where medals > (select AVG(medals) from countries_athletes_who_wo_gold) ;
```

but am not getting the required output?

Comment: Have you tried without the `VIEW`? It looks all you would need to do to try is replace the two references to the view name in the query with `results where medals = 'Gold'`.  Actually, is it that perhaps you need to sum medals by country first, then take the average of that, then find the countries whose total medals exceed the average of the counties' totals?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. What output are you expecting, what are you getting instead?

Comment: I want to list all Countries which won more than the average number of (any) medal in this case Gold

Comment: The number of medals isn't in the `medals` column, that contains the medal color. Why are you trying to average that?

Comment: You should be averaging `awarded_medals_medal-id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to write a query that counts the medals for each country.

```
SELECT EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY, COUNT(*) AS medal_count
FROM Countries_Athletes_who_wo_Gold
GROUP BY EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY
```

Then use this as a subquery twice in your query: once to get each country's medal count, and then to get the average across all countries.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY, COUNT(*) AS medal_count
    FROM Countries_Athletes_who_wo_Gold
    GROUP BY EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY
) AS by_country
JOIN (SELECT AVG(medal_count) AS avg_medals
      FROM (SELECT EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY, COUNT(*) AS medal_count
            FROM Countries_Athletes_who_wo_Gold
            GROUP BY EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY) AS by_country
      ) AS all_countries
WHERE medal_count > avg_medals
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fb29/7)

Comment: Do I have to sum the number of gold medals won by a country?

Comment: its just the ids for the medal types ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to get the counts correctly.